# Insert docs in sorted order on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In mongodb, I want to insert the data in sorted order based on some field.
The way I am doing, before insertion compare the data with data which is in collection and then insert it on that particular position. Is the insertion at particular position is possible in mongodb using node.js

Comment: thats not the way databases work, use indexes instead

Comment: @lante is correct, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/. You need to select/design database indexing method in order to support your query. I adopted a solution for my question by using this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert a doc at a specific spot in the collection. Even if you could, it wouldn't matter because you can't rely on the natural order of MongoDB documents staying consistent as they can move over time as the docs in a collection are updated.

Instead, create an index on the field(s) you need your docs sorted on and then include a sort clause in your queries to efficiently retrieve the docs in that order.

Example in the shell:

```
// Create the index (do this once)
db.test.ensureIndex({someField: 1})

// Sorted query
db.test.find().sort({someField: 1})
```

Comment: Thanks Johnny, I used already ensureIndex({somefield:1}). The problem is it will consume more memory as long as more data is inserted into the collection. Let suppose collection count is 9 lacks, so insertion of the document is continuous going on in the db. At that time background indexing operation taking more memory, which cause memory issues.

Comment: @user3118131 You do need to make sure you have enough memory to keep the index in RAM.